# What are the font properties in WPF that are inherited through the visual tree?

Tags: wpf, fonts, dependency-properties, visual-tree

WPF has certain font properties that are inherited through the visual tree. This for instance allows changing of the `FontFamily` on a `UserControl` and have all the text in it reflect that change.

What are all the font-related properties that are passed via inheritance in the visual tree?

Answer (score 1):

The properties are:

- [TextElement.Foreground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.foreground.aspx)
- [TextElement.FontFamily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontfamily.aspx)
- [TextElement.FontSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontsize.aspx)
- [TextElement.FontStretch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontstretch.aspx)
- [TextElement.FontStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontstyle.aspx)
- [TextElement.FontWeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontweight.aspx)

Since they are attached properties, they can be set on types in the visual tree that do not have explicit dependency properties (such as `Foreground`) defined on them.